# PHPMailer send email with array

Tags: php, html-email

Hi I have question about HTML form array and PHP. For example I have name and email but ask 6 times and I want to send this mail. What I should edit to work? thank you!

**HTML:**

```
   <form  method="Post" action="send.php" onSubmit="return validate();">
    <?php
     $amount=6; //amount shows the number of data I want to repeat
     for( $i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++ ) {
        ?>
        <b>Data <?php echo $i+1 ?>º</b>
          <input type="edit" name="Name[]" size="40">
          <input type="edit" name="email[]" size="40">
          <br>
    <?php } ?>
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="send 6 data mail">
   </form>
```

**send.php:**

```
<?php
       require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
       $name= $_POST['name[]']; 
       $email= $_POST['email[]']; 
       $mail = new PHPMailer();
       ...
       $mail->Body = ' Data<br> '
    <?php
     $amount=6; //amount shows the number of data I want to repeat
     for( $i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++ ) {
        ?> '
       name: '.$name[$i].' email: '.$email[$i];
       ...
       $mail->Send();
?>
```

should send:

```
Data
name: nameinput1 email: emailinput1
name: nameinput2 email: emailinput2
name: nameinput3 email: emailinput3
name: nameinput4 email: emailinput4
name: nameinput5 email: emailinput5
name: nameinput6 email: emailinput6
```

Comment: `POST` vars come in without the brackets. So instead of `$_POST['name[]']` refer to them as `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: You can simply count one of them and assign it to `$amount`. And you can use `$_POST["name"]`. See my answer for further detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following;

```
 <?php
    require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $name= $_POST['name']; 
    $email= $_POST['email'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    ...
    $mail->Body = ' Data<br> ';
    $amount=count($name); //amount shows the number of data I want to repeat
    for( $i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++ ) {
        $mail->Body .= 'name: '.$name[$i].' email: '.$email[$i];
    } 
    ...
    $mail->Send();
?>
```

Comment: no dont give any error junt remain blank (if I do only one works)

Comment: Your form name is `Name` on frontend, could you please update that and try? And you have missing bracket on for loop. See my updated answer

Comment: I used your update remaining the same :\
I insert $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; and not show erros

Comment: What is the result of `$mail->Send();` ? You need to provide more details. There must be some errors

Comment: $mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->IsSMTP();

Comment: $mail->Host = "mail.myhost";
$mail->Port = myPort;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mail';
$mail->Password = 'pass of email';
$mail->From = "myemail";
$mail->Sender = "myemail";
$mail->FromName = "From website";
$mail->AddAddress('myemail', 'MyWebsite');
$mail->IsHTML(true); $mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; 
$mail->Subject  = "Mensage ".$time;
$mail->Body = ' <b>'.$name[$i].'</b> ';

Comment: (error log was disabled)Error is in send.php
[28-Apr-2014 11:16:17 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR)

Comment: @po1725 you have syntax issues. Could you please see my updated code and apply it on your side

Comment: @BABAL syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) and '?' I think it is not recognizing the separation of the BODY html to PHP
$mail->Body = ' HTML '<?php echo $i ?>' HTML';

Comment: But there is no echo in my script?

Comment: Im using line of position 'echo $i' I removed and used your code and I have errors in the seperator HTML to PHP  syntax error, unexpected '?'

Comment: Which line? What is there at that line?

Comment: line of the error I have 'name: '.$name[$i].' email: '.$email[$i]; and say PHP syntax error, unexpected '?' a little snood?

Comment: I found the problem
$name= $name.$i;   $email= $email.$i;  
echo $$name.' ' ;echo $$email.' ' ;
thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
$mail->Body = ' Data<br> ';
 $amount=6; //amount shows the number of data I want to repeat
 for( $i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++ ) {
   $mail->Body .= 'name: '.$name[$i].' email: '.$email[$i]."<br>";
 }
   ...
$mail->Send();
?>
```