# Printing just the value of an array in email body with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, phpmailer

I'd like to print just the value from an array into the body of a email using PHPmailer.

I can get just the value from an array using this code, whereas $row[0] is the specific array I want

```
foreach ($row[0] as $key => $val) {
  echo $val;
}
```

But, I can not include this in the PHPmailer body. I need to use either text within "" or a single variable. From what I've tried, at least, because it seems like everything else is rejected...

I'm probably missing something, perhaps there's an easy solution. Thank you, the help is appreciated!

Comment: Please see here "PHPMailer send email with array - Stack Overflow" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293043/phpmailer-send-email-with-array

Answer (score 0):

Not too complicated:

```php
foreach ($row[0] as $key => $val) {
  $mail->Body .= $val . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better implode the array and set in mail body

```
$mail->body=implode(" ",$rows);
```